# Check if value exists in an ordered dictionary

Tags: python

I'm getting an ordered dictionary in the python variable `snapshot`. How can I check to see if a value `'Operator'` exists in the dictionary?

```
OrderedDict([('1111', {'location': 'Nakuru', 'uid': '1111'}), ('lkhsdfalsdkfh', {'designation': 'Operator', 'id': 2, 'location': 'Kisii', 'mobile': '0722112889', 'name': 'Njeri', 'uid': '2222'})])
```

I have attempted to use

```
if thepassword in snapshot.values():
```

But this doesn't seem to give me the correct output.

Comment: You forgot to include the code you wrote that is producing the incorrect output.

Comment: It looks like the keys are the passwords... If so your if statement should read: `if thepassword in snapshot:`

Comment: Or more explicitly `if thepassword in snapshot.keys()`

Comment: @ Joseph Budin's answer works because the passwords are the keys, thanks. am leaving the question open for the case where they are not the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `Operator` is a value inside one of the ***nested*** dictionaries. By checking `in snapshot.values()` you check if it's one of the ***keys***. You will have to do:

```py
for d in snapshot.values():
    if thepassword in d.values():
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer given is fine if you don't need to know where the value is in `snapshot`, but only that it does exist.  This code returns a tuple with the two keys necessary to traverse to the value you're looking for:

```
keys = None
for okey, oval in snapshot.items():
    revDict = dict((v, k) for k, v in oval.items())
    if 'Operator' in revDict:
        keys = (okey, revDict['Operator'])
        break
print(keys)
```

Result:

```
('lkhsdfalsdkfh', 'designation')
```